# CRUD operations C# (delete)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

```
    я хочу с помощью ID удалить информацию которая находится в бд, но почему то не получаются
  public void Detele()
    {
          using(VideoGamesDatabaseContext context = new VideoGamesDatabaseContext())
        {
            VideoGame d = context.VideoGames.Find();
            if(d != null)
            {
                context.VideoGames.Remove(d);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: В Find надо что-то передать, наверное?

Answer (score 0):

Сформируй `d` с помощью `linq`:
`VideoGame d = context.VideoGames.Where(v => v.Id == _Id).FirstOrDefault();`
где `_Id` - это айдишник елемента, который ты хочешь удалить

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Detele(Int32 id)
{
    using(VideoGamesDatabaseContext context = new VideoGamesDatabaseContext())
    {
        VideoGame d = context.VideoGames.Find();
        if(d != null)
        {
            Int32 remove = d.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            context.VideoGames.Remove(remove);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что то не то у вас с типами переменных.